# How to put the app in background without opening any single UI related class in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a requirement from client with two points
1. First a notification will generate after two minutes.
2. On click on icon in application list, nothing should happen.

First point I have done, but don't have any clue of how to implement the second point.

Please advise if any have about how to create app with no UI but only a background notification and nothing should happen on clicking on the icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but what you're after is not possible on the iPhone. The primary class that represents your application is called [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for a reason. It is part of UIKit.

It sounds as if your client is an Android user, because Android provides this ability via its [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class. But nothing of the sort exists for iOS. Your challenge is now in dealing with your client, not in dealing with software!

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done in for any official Appstore apps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting `exit(0);` at the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` **but this will surely get your app rejected**.

If you do this you also have to schedule your notification in the same method. Lke:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

  //do your stuff

  exit(0);    //this line kills the app
  return NO;  //this line is just to make compiler happy
}
```

See also [How send application to background when install on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664595/how-send-application-to-background-when-install-on-device/9666840#9666840), it was asked today.